# Is there anything Ruby Mixins can do what C# pseudo Mixins (Interface + Extension Methods) can't?

Tags: c#, .net, ruby, mixins

I'm trying to get a better sense of `Ruby`. So Ruby makes `Mixins` a first class concept. In `C#` one can create `Extension Methods` that act on `Interfaces`. So both techniques provide a mechanism that is widely known as a `Mixin`.

It might be good to compare both approaches on a specific example.

**Enumerable in Ruby**

Let's take all those beautiful methods that work up on a collection. In Ruby those are `all?`, `any?`, `count` and a lot more: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html

From the documentation:
*The Enumerable mixin provides collection classes with several traversal and searching methods, and with the ability to sort. The class must provide a method each, which yields successive members of the collection.*

**Enumerable in C#**

In `C#` there is the feature called `LINQ` that also provides those methods `All`, `Any`, `Count` and a lot more.

If you want to make your class "`LINQ enabled`" you need to implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface which forces you to also provide a method `GetEnumerator` which conceptually is very close to the ruby approach.

So from the perspective of a bird your class now gained all those methods mentioned above. How did it happend?

Well `.NET` defined all those `LINQ` methods as `Extension Methods` on the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. And since you implemented this interface you now "mixin" all those methods.

I wonder how much both approaches differ and if there are things `Ruby Mixins` can do that `C#'s` `Interface` + `Extension Method` Strategy can't? Well, beside the fact that `Ruby Mixins` can be mixed at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are quite similar conceptually, but C#'s version is more conservative - Ruby Mixins get access to private instance variables, and can define private methods, or even replace methods. C# Extension Methods can only define public methods, and don't get any special access rights.

Ruby Mixins actually *change* the class, whereas Extension Methods are a method dispatch trick (the compiler says, "Any instance methods with name *Foo()*? Any Extension Methods? Yes? I'll just emit this as a call to this static method instead").

One other difference, is that Extension Methods are *scoped*, whereas Mixins are not (you cannot specify which Mixins you want in a Ruby file, once they're declared somewhere else, they're bolted on for life). Ruby has talked about adding this (they have some name for it, "specifications" or something?), but it ends up being quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Mixins are classes parameterized by their superclass. There really isn't any relation at all to Extension Methods, so it doesn't even make sense to compare them.